Telebot | Можно ли пригласить бота с помощью отправленной ссылки?
Я хочу узнать возможно ли сделать так чтобы бот мог самостоятельно заходить в телеграмм чат отправляя в чат с ботом саму ссылку от чата. Все что я нашел это get.chat а как с ней пользоваться так чтобы заставить бота зайти в чат я не знаю.
Пошагово:

Начинаешь чат с ботом с помощью команды /start
Бот отправляет сообщение типа ,,Чтобы добавить бота отправьте ссылку приглашения в чат,,
Отправляешь ссылку боту в чат.
Бот самостоятельно заходит в чат.

Код:
chat_link = message.text
        try:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Проверка ссылки...')
            # Присоединение к чату (если ссылка валидная и бот имеет права присоединиться)
            chat_info = bot.get_chat(chat_link)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Бот успешно присоединился к чату!')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не удалось присоединиться к чату. Пожалуйста, убедитесь, что ссылка правильная и бот имеет права присоединиться.')

